# Can I get a list/library's Relative URL using PnP when I have its ID?

Tags: spfx, pnp

I tried grabbing it by calling

```
web.lists.getById([THE ID]).get()
```

but the relative server URL was not in the payload. Is there another method I should use or is there a REST endpoint that provides this info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the `RootFolder` property of a list.

Modify your code as from below sample code :

```
sp.web.lists.getById([THE ID]).select("Title","RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl")
.expand("RootFolder").get().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked just as expected. Thanks so much!